# Checking incoming call notification in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am working on iPhone game application, in which user can  play game and records some data.

My problem is that the application not supporting background processing. In my application if call's appearing then my application is terminated. But I need to save user current state.

I have read some blog and post in which they have mention that core telephony frame work can give us all such state and notification. But someone mention that core telephony API is an private API. If will use this API then APPLE accept my application or not? I need to save my application current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the answers in the wrong place. You do not need any access to the telephony API.

Apps by default enter the background and return to the foreground, on modern devices and iOS versions - Perhaps you are running your app on an older device or on iOS version 3.x, in which case all apps (not just yours) will be terminated when they are "exited".

Even in this case the solution is not the telephony API, but handling a notification sent to your app about your application terminating - You can save state there, and then reload it when your app is re-run.

Check out these links for more information:

- [App states and transitions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1)
- [Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1)

Comment: I had implemented termination notification . but I need to check app termination reason  is telephone or not. if this then i need to save state

Comment: I have save application state on app termination and when app is start  then I will perfrom to all those thing regarding app state

Comment: How come you want to save the state on a phone call, and otherwise you don't? Also, you still didn't make it clear why your app doesn't enter the background and return properly.

Comment: I have read the App states and transitions documentation .As per apple documetation app will gives 5 seconds in which we need to save our un saved data